# How to reverse search in Netbeans?

Tags: regex, netbeans

In Netbeans I can find every file including a `footer(_something).php` using this regex:

`footer.*\.php`.

Now I want to reverse this and find every file that *doesn't* include any kind of footer file.

I tried this negative lookahead but it doesn't seem to work.

`(?!footer.*\.php)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: add anchors.http://regex101.com/r/dP9rO4/3